# plaid - android - httpclient library version mismatch

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, plaid

I am using plaid-java:0.2.10 as a dependency in my Android app.

Plaid uses org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 as a dependency. And, android also includes the same library as a dependency.

However, there is a mismatch in their versions. I get the following error when i build using gradle,

Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

I want to use the one provided by plaid.

How do i get this to work? Is there a way to ignore the library provided by android?

Answer (score 1):

> Question - is it not possible to ignore the apachehttpclient library provided by google and use a newer version of the library instead?

It is not. The [Apache HttpClient Android Port](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) can deployed along-side with the old version shipped with the platform.

> Why isnt this possible?

It is believed to be for security reasons.

Comment: so, i am currently in this situation : The plaid library uses 'apachehttpclient' code. So how can i deploy the android port? Is there a tutorial or something. do i exclude the 'apachehttpclient' dependency and include 'apachehttpandroidclient' dependency in my android project? Will that solve the problem. This is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i found this at the Apache website,

Google Android 1.0 was released with a pre-BETA snapshot of Apache HttpClient. To coincide with the first Android release Apache HttpClient 4.0 APIs had to be frozen prematurely, while many of interfaces and internal structures were still not fully worked out. As Apache HttpClient 4.0 was maturing the project was expecting Google to incorporate the latest code improvements into their code tree. Unfortunately it did not happen. Version of Apache HttpClient shipped with Android has effectively become a fork. Eventually Google decided to discontinue further development of their fork while refusing to upgrade to the stock version of Apache HttpClient citing compatibility concerns as a reason for such decision. As a result those Android developers who would like to continue using Apache HttpClient APIs on Android cannot take advantage of newer features, performance improvements and bug fixes.

Question - is it not possible to ignore the apachehttpclient library provided by google and use a newer version of the library instead? Why isnt this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the below code snippet in the dependencies section in the build.gradle file of you app module.

```
  configurations {
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
```